# Can I use Blazor Wasm Standalone with Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: blazor-webassembly, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a simple question, can I use the Microsoft.Identity.Web library on a Blazor standalone app?

I have downloaded the template pack of the MIW library (`microsoft.identity.Web.ProjectTemplates-1.0.0`) and the Blazor standalone one (blazorwasm2) don't make use of the MIW library, but the Blazor Server one does.